# PHP Amazon S3 - Error 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature' error?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get all buckets from a S3 host but I'm having problems with the AWS Signature

I followed every step on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html.

My code is inspired from https://github.com/avi-wish/aws4-signature-php/blob/master/aws_secure_request.php

Do I miss something? what am I doing wrong. I made a working version of it in Postman where I can GET & CREATE buckets. Thanks in advance for the reply.

```
"Code": "SignatureDoesNotMatch",
"Message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details.",
```

```
 public function signature($secretAccessKey, $region, $service, $date, $timeStamp, $httpRequestMethod, $host, $uri, $payload): array
    {
        $debugCanonicalRequest = [];
        $debugStringToSign = [];

        $canonicalRequest = [];
        $canonicalHeaders = [];
        $stringToSign = [];

        $phpAlgorithm = 'sha256';
        $aws4_request = 'aws4_request';
        $algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
        $canonicalQueryString = '';
        $signedHeaders = 'content-type;host;x-amz-date';

        $canonicalHeaders[] = 'content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        $canonicalHeaders[] = 'host:' . $host;
        $canonicalHeaders[] = 'x-amz-date:' . $timeStamp;
        $canonicalHeadersStr = implode("\n", $canonicalHeaders);

        $canonicalRequest[] = $debugCanonicalRequest["HTTP verb"] = $httpRequestMethod;
        $canonicalRequest[] = $debugCanonicalRequest["canonical URI"] = $uri;
        $canonicalRequest[] = $debugCanonicalRequest["canonical query string"] = $canonicalQueryString;
        $canonicalRequest[] = $debugCanonicalRequest["canonical headers"] = $canonicalHeadersStr . "\n";
        $canonicalRequest[] = $debugCanonicalRequest["Signed headers"] = $signedHeaders;
        $canonicalRequest[] = hash($phpAlgorithm, $payload);
        $debugCanonicalRequest["hashed payload"] = hash($phpAlgorithm, $payload);

        $requestCanonicalRequest = implode("\n", $canonicalRequest);
        $debugCanonicalRequest["full canonical request"] = implode("\n", $canonicalRequest);

        $stringToSign[] = $debugStringToSign["algorithm"] = $algorithm;
        $stringToSign[] = $debugStringToSign["timestamp"] = $timeStamp;
        $stringToSign[] = $debugStringToSign["scope"] = implode('/', [$date, $region, $service, $aws4_request]);
        $stringToSign[] = hash($phpAlgorithm, utf8_encode($requestCanonicalRequest));

        $stringToSignStr = $debugStringToSign["full string to sign"] = implode("\n", $stringToSign);

        $dateKey = hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $date, 'AWS4' . $secretAccessKey, true);
        $dateRegionKey = hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $region, $dateKey, true);
        $dateRegionServiceKey = hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $service, $dateRegionKey, true);
        $signingKey = hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $aws4_request, $dateRegionServiceKey, true);
        return ["signature" => hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $stringToSignStr, $signingKey), "debug" => ["CanonicalRequest" => $debugCanonicalRequest, "StringToSign" => $debugStringToSign]];
    }

    public function s3Request(): bool|string
    {
        $accessKey = [[accessKey]];
        $secretKey = [[secretKey]];
        $region = "us-east-1";
        $service = "s3";
        $httpRequestMethod = "GET";
        $uri = '/';
        $host = [[host]];
        $payload = "";

        $currentDateTime = new DateTime('UTC');
        $date = $currentDateTime->format('Ymd');
        $timeStamp = $currentDateTime->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
        $signature = $this->signature($secretKey, $region, $service, $date, $timeStamp, $httpRequestMethod, $host, $uri, $payload);
        $content = hash("sha256", $payload);

        $headers = [
            'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: ' . $content,
            'X-Amz-Date: ' . $timeStamp,
            'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' . $accessKey . '/' . $date . '/' . $region . '/' . $service . '/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=' . $signature["signature"]
        ];

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://192.168.1.18:9020/",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $httpRequestMethod,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        return json_encode([$signature["debug"], "headers" => $headers, "response" => $this->utility->responseConverter($response, "xmlBody")]);
    }
```